# Freeradius: Authenticate users on certain condition

Tags: freeradius

There is a network where users are using PPPoE to establish connections to the Access servers. We have lost the billing system and users' DB. The only condition that we know is that 'Valid credential should be credential where username and password are the same value.  (i.e. username: johnsmith, password: johnsmith)'.

We'd like to recover access to the Internet asap.

Setup that we have now: Ubuntu 2004, accel-ppp, freeradius3. Everything works fine but we have to add a record for each user to `raddb/mods-config/files/authorize` file.

```
user1 Cleartext-Password := "user1"
user2 Cleartext-Password := "user2"
userN Cleartext-Password := "userN"
```

Updated: Is that possible to avoid manually adding users? The script should verify credential assuming that username and valid password are the same value.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can generate this config file using a script?

Comment: No. The script that checks if username = password. If yes then authenticate/authorize as a valid user.

Comment: OK, can you expand that again to a fulsome question? Your edit isn't using full sentences, so while I'm sure you have a reasonable technical question, I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sure. Let me try. Keep in mind that there is no DB, there is no list of users stored on the server side. The protocol is PPPoE. Now, CHAP requires that both the client and server know the plaintext of the secret. All users of the network provide a password which always is equavalent to %{User-Name} value. So password is known on the both sides. The script should verify that condition and allow to open a session.

Comment: OK, that's a bit clearer now, thanks. I can't answer it myself, but if you get stuck for replies, consider [asking it on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), as there may be more people who can help there.

Comment: This question [has now been posted to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084170/freeradius-authenticate-users-on-certain-condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial to do in unlang, FreeRADIUS's configuration language.

The "known" clear password to be matched in FreeRADIUS must be made available in the `Cleartext-Password` attribute. This is where it will generally be placed after a successful database lookup.

As you know the `User-Name`, you can update the password to match it. In `sites-enabled/default` you can add:

```
update control {
    &Cleartext-Password = &request:User-Name
}
```

Adding this right at the bottom of the `authorize{}` section, and using `=` above (rather than `:=`) means that the `Cleartext-Password` attribute will only be changed if it hasn't previously been set by some other method, ensuring that as you add entries back into a database they will take precedence.

Authentication will then compare `User-Name` to `Cleartext-Password`; they will of course match so access will be permitted.